# Conditionally adding Context Menu Item in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2010

In my outlook 2010 AddIn, I want to add context menu Item when user right click on Appointment Item.  However I don't want to add context menu item blindly, instead context menu Item will differ if user belong to different user group.  How can I achieve this functionality with XML configuration file.  I can add context menu item with native code but don't know how it can be done using config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML file add the XML tag `getVisible` and point it to a method that calculates group membership, returning a `true` or `false`.

For an excellent example see Norm Estrabrook's post: [Show and Hide Context Menu Items in Outlook 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/12/show-and-hide-context-menu-items-in-outlook-2010-norm-estabrook.aspx)